# How can I push tab bar controller after click a button from a view in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, button, tabbarcontroller

I have a button in a view,  I want to add tab bar controller after click the button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, i don't think pushing a tab bar as a subview as a good idea

but if you still want to do this, there's a lot of way to work around

one of them is by using modalview

first you have to add this code after you make the button

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

it attach an event listener to the button you have

next, you make the event function to do the tab bar pushing

```
-(void)buttonTapped: (UIButton *)sender
{
        YourTabBarClass *myTabBar = [[YourTabBarClass alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        myTabBar.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

        [self presentModalViewController:myTabBar animated:YES];
}
```

and dont forget to import the tabbarcontroller class header file in your .m

```
#import "YourTabBarClass.h"
```

hope this help ;)

edit : if you need to go back from the tab bar view into the previous menu, you can add a button, give it an event listener, and put this code inside the function

```
[self resignFirstResponder];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)BtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *searchViewController = [[[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
searchViewController.title = @"Search";

UIViewController *exploreViewController = [[[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExploreViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
exploreViewController.title = @"Explore";

UIViewController *dialerViewController = [[[DialerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DialerViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
dialerViewController.title = @"Dialer";

self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc]init]autorelease];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchViewController, exploreViewController, dialerViewController, nil];

[self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
}
```

Don't forget to create the corresponding nib files(dialerViewController.xib, SearchViewController.xib, DialerViewController.xib) and make these views hight to 411px(this is unto you)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is for Swift
Set your button action then use this one

```
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = (your viewcontroller) index
```

Example:

```
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
```