# Nav Bar Item in XIB that Presents a StoryBoard Tab Bar Root View Controller Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

My App has a lot going on with it, lol.  On my Main Menu, if you click "Chat", it will take you to the Chat XIB.

[image]
[image]

If you look to the top left in the Navigation Bar I have something called "Main Menu".  I want this to take me back to the Main Menu.  My Main Menu is on the main.Storyboard.  The Chat is an XIB.  Both Views have Tab Bars.  I've been going in circles all day trying to figure this out.  This is the last thing I have tried which crashes:

```
-(void)MainMenu
{
    MainMenuTabBarControllerViewController *MMTBC = [[MainMenuTabBarControllerViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:MMTBC animated:YES];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Group";
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(actionNew)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Main Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(MainMenu)];

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    chatrooms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: What's the crash message? Can you catch which line it crashes?

Comment: I get this error with Pop: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to get popped view controller.'

Comment: I need to somehow dismiss the rootviewcontroller and reassign it when the user click Main Menu

Comment: could you also add code about how to go from `MainMenuTabBarControllerViewController` to the other tab view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two tab bar controllers in your application. I don't think it is a good idea to use navigation controller (push/pop) to manage the transition between them. Try with [presentViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:).

When the chat button is pressed, show the second tab view controller.

```
- (IBAction)chatButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    ChatTabBarController *chatTabView = ... // allocate memory and initialize
    [self presentViewController:chatTabView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When the main menu button is pressed, dismiss it.

```
- (IBAction)mainMenuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Edit:

Just notice a very similar question being asked a couple of years ago. Take a look at this one:

[How can I push tab bar controller after click a button from a view in objective c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805215/)

Comment: is it bad that i created my navigation and tab bar in the action of opening the chat view?  see screenshot:  http://pho.to/8iWQI

Comment: Yip. You should put them in the `-init` method.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate a little on putting them in the init method?

Comment: And also, you really share the code in your screenshot. The `viewDidLoad` that you show is not related to whatever you were asking. If you have question about the GUI design stuff. You can open a new question ask about that. Right?

Comment: the [-init](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init) method is default initialization method for any `NSObject`. You are also using it. But you are just not putting the initialization code there.

Comment: So this is what I ended up doing which I thought worked...but however when it takes me back to the main menu (CRV) it is frozen and none of the buttons or tab bar buttons work.  http://pho.to/8iWnB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69565/discussion-between-yuchen-zhong-and-diplomatic-medic).

Answer (score 0):

You should use storyboards. Try deleting your XIB and start using an `Unwind segue` on your storyboard. Are you using push or modal? It changes everything. After you migrate to storyboards, read Apple's docs on Unwind segues.

Best regards,

Comment: I'm using PopToViewController, should I be using present, push or modal?  I get this error with Pop:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to get popped view controller.'

Comment: When I try Push it pushes me to the Main Menu, but it doesn't dismiss the Chat XIB Tab Bar Controller:  http://pho.to/8iT0v