# iOS custom segue return from slide in overlay view

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, xcode6, ios8.1

Here is the controllerviews' structure in storyboard:

```
[tableviewcontroller]   [tableviewcontroller]    [FilterMenuController]
      |                           |
[navigationcontroller] [navigationcontroller]
               |         |
         [tabbarcontroller]
```

Now in second tableview controller I have following code to present a slide in overlay filter menu view. Which will be over TabbarController.

```
- (IBAction)didPushFiterButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    FilterMenuTableViewController *tlc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FilterMenuController"];
[tlc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [self.tabBarController addChildViewController:tlc];
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:tlc.view];
    [tlc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [tlc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, self.tabBarController.view.frame.size.width, self.tabBarController.view.frame.size.height)];
    }];

}
```

Now, I want that if push on a **button** within the **filter view**, filter view will be gone and the tableview will be reloaded. I wrote a custom segue. But really messed. Either tableview is not reloading or navigation bar and tabbar is lost.

Can you give me some idea how to write this segue? or how to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: You can take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139754/nav-bar-item-in-xib-that-presents-a-storyboard-tab-bar-root-view-controller-segu/28141428#28141428. Your question is very similar, you have a tabBar and a isolated view. So a good way to do is to show it as a pop up and dismiss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed this problem. Hope it can help others.

Basically, I should not have tried to use a segue to solve this problem. **`Delegate`** should be the cure.

So set the table view controller as the `FilterViewController`'s delegate. When button within `FilterViewController` is pushed. The delegate method in `TableViewController` will remove the `filterView` and reload the data.